# A closed range can never be empty, Why?

Tags: swift, range

Given the following line of code (Swift 4.x.x):

`let someRange = 0...2`

It is apparent that this closed range cannot be empty as it has a lower bound and an upper bound.

But I want to know if there is any further explanation why any closed range can **never** be empty?

This Question comes from Raywenderlich - Swift Apprentice

Comment: Directly from the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange: Because a closed range includes its upper bound, a closed range whose lower bound is equal to the upper bound contains that value. Therefore, a ClosedRange instance cannot represent an empty range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Closed Range contains both its lower bound and its upper bound.

So even if you wrote:

```
let someRange = 0...0
```

It still contains one element: `0`.

How would you attempt write an empty range?  `let someRange = ...` ??
That doesn't make much sense, and if you specify either the upper or lower bound, it is immediately non-empty.

Comment: That is what I wanted to confirm.

Thank you

Comment: Why is e.g. `0 ... -1` not allowed? IMHO that would be a well-defined and empty closed range (i.e. all elements >= 0 and <= -1, which is the empty set).